# Catch ValueError in multiple parts of program

Tags: python, error-handling, python-3.5, valueerror

I am trying to raise a `ValueError` when a variable becomes negative. My problem is that this variable changes values in a few parts of my program. How could I achieve the same result as below with only one `raise` statement?

```
import random

a = 5

while True:

    a -= random.randint(0,10)
    if a < 0:
        raise ValueError('Cannot be negative')

    a += random.randint(0,10)
    if a < 0:
        raise ValueError('Cannot be negative')

    a -= random.randint(0,10)
    if a < 0:
        raise ValueError('Cannot be negative')

    a += random.randint(0,10)
    if a < 0:
        raise ValueError('Cannot be negative')
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using a getter/setter for your variable, and check in the setter. This is exactly the sort of reason they exist

Comment: Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to raise the error just when it becomes negative, you have to check for ValueError every time you decrease the variable. You do not need to check for ValueError after an addition, since if it was not negative, it will not be negative after the addition. If you want to put the line `raise ValueError('Cannot be negative')` only once in your code, then this is a way:

```
import random

a = 5

while True:

    a -= random.randint(0,10)
    if a < 0:
        raise ValueError('Cannot be negative')
    a += random.randint(0,10)
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, this was only a simple example to illustrate how my variable is changed multiple times in my code. Can I use something such as `with raise` and `while`?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you desire from the program? I do not seem to understand what you would like to use and when you would like the `ValueError` to occur.